# Restrict indexing of fields when writing them to Elasticsearch through Spark. So that field cannot be used in query but still store in ES as doc

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

This can be achieved through giving specifying "index": false for particular field. Now the problem is how it can be reproduced in Spark.

```
PUT hostname:9200/index1

{
    "index1": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "business_address": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": false,
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "business_city": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Could you please share spark code as what you've tried?

Comment: spark.read.format("es").options(opt).load("index1")
used in spark to read data already present in ES. But now I want to write this data to new index and disable indexing on some field.                                                                       Also since this gives Spark Dataframe, I have schema/mapping already.

Comment: Sounds like you need`_reindex`

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a source index and you would **want to create** a destination index with some of the fields set with `index:false` in mapping and then perform the reindex. All this via spark. Correct?

Comment: Yes @OpsterESNinja-Kamal

Comment: @hodda hey sorry forgot to ask you, you would need solution in which language Python, Java or Scala?

Comment: Scala with spark